# Android Indy wallet backup and restore issue

Tags: android, hyperledger, wallet, hyperledger-indy

I am trying to restore and backup Indy wallet but I am getting IO exception. Read and write permission already given but still same. Is anyone faced this issue ? I am trying this sample

https://github.com/ap050492/Hyperledger-Indy-Wallet---Android

E/ExportWalletTask: java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@8db6758[Not completed]

Comment: This issue is fixed now was due to Android 12 write access restriction.